# python mechanize returns 403 Forbidden, openssl s_client works

Tags: python, certificate, client, mechanize

I'm trying to use mechanize to connect to https service which requires client certificate.
Unfortunately every time I'm trying to request home page, I'm getting 403 Forbidden.
Using this same cert and key, I can connect with browser and with openssl s_client. I've compared headers and with browser and mechanize they are exactly same (user-agent, accept, etc), but with s_client they are empty.
With mechanize I tried to request base url which rediretcs to the one I need, and with enabled debugging I see that ale redirects works fine, only the last url returns 403. 
Where Can I look to find solution for this problem ?

Comment: maybe they check the UserAgent string?

Comment: I've copied all headers from real browser request (which works fine). Also request from openssl s_client works, even if there are no headers at all...